# Unresponsive hamburger icon in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

[youtube reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27JtRAI3QO8)

I was trying to make a website by following a YouTube tutorial and i cant seem to toggle the navigation bar it doesnt collapse. I have tried different videos but it is still not working.
I am very new to programming and this is my first project.
Thank-you in advance for your guidance.

```js
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu'),
  navToggle = document.getElementById('nav-toogle'),
  navClose = document.getElementById('nav-close')

if (navToggle) {
  navToggle.addEventListner('click', () => {
    navMenu.classList.add('show-menu')
  })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Julius+Sans+One&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0;
  font-size: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --hue-color: 250;
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
  --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);
  --container-color: #fff;
  --body-font: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  --mb-0-25: .25rem;
  --mb-0-5: .5rem;
  --mb-0-75: .75rem;
  --mb-1: 1rem;
  --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
  --mb-2: 2rem;
  --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
  --mb-3: 3rem;
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --z-model: 1000;
}

.section {
  padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
}

.section__subtitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-3);
}

.section__title,
.section__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin-left: var(--mb-1-5);
  margin-right: var(--mb-1-5);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

.nav {
  max-width: 968px;
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__logo,
.nav__toggle {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.nav__logo:hover {
  color: var(--first-color)
}

.nav__toggle {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__toggle:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__list {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
}

.nav__link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.nav__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.3rem;
  bottom: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__close:hover {
  color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.show {
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
   :root {
    --big-font-size: 3rem;
    --h1-font-size: 2.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: .875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .813rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem 4rem;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 0;
    transition: .3s;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Megisto, Beats, Music">
    <meta name="author" content="Nitin Remella">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <header class="header" id="header">
    <nav class="nav container">
      <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Goku</a>


      <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
        <ul class="nav__list grid">
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-estate nav__icon"></i> HOME
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-user nav__icon"></i> About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#music" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-music nav__icon"></i> Music
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#Products" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-box nav__icon"></i> Products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-message nav__icon"></i> Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <i class="uil uil-times nav__close" id="nav-close"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="nav__btns">
        <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
          <i class="uil uil-apps"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>



















  <main class="l-main">

  </main>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two typos in your JS code: The ID "nav-toggle"/"nav-toogle", and "addEventListner" (missing "e")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have fixed it but still you should follow the tutorial properly

```js
const navMenu = document.getElementById("nav-menu"),
  navToggle = document.getElementById("nav-toggle"),
  navClose = document.getElementById("nav-close");

if (navToggle) {
  navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("test");
    navMenu.classList.add("show-menu");
  });
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Julius+Sans+One&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0;
  font-size: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

 :root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --hue-color: 250;
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
  --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);
  --container-color: #fff;
  --body-font: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
  --normal-font-size: 0.938rem;
  --small-font-size: 0.813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: 0.75rem;
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  --mb-0-25: 0.25rem;
  --mb-0-5: 0.5rem;
  --mb-0-75: 0.75rem;
  --mb-1: 1rem;
  --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
  --mb-2: 2rem;
  --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
  --mb-3: 3rem;
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --z-model: 1000;
}

.section {
  padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
}

.section__subtitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-3);
}

.section__title,
.section__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin-left: var(--mb-1-5);
  margin-right: var(--mb-1-5);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

.nav {
  max-width: 968px;
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__logo,
.nav__toggle {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.nav__logo:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__toggle {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__toggle:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__list {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
}

.nav__link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.nav__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.3rem;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__close:hover {
  color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.show-menu {
  bottom: 0 !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
   :root {
    --big-font-size: 3rem;
    --h1-font-size: 2.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: 0.875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: 0.813rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem 4rem;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Megisto, Beats, Music" />
  <meta name="author" content="Nitin Remella" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css" />

  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <nav class="nav container">
      <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Goku</a>

      <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
        <ul class="nav__list grid">
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-estate nav__icon"></i> HOME
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-user nav__icon"></i> About
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#music" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-music nav__icon"></i> Music
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#Products" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-box nav__icon"></i> Products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav__link">
              <i class="uil uil-message nav__icon"></i> Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <i class="uil uil-times nav__close" id="nav-close"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="nav__btns">
        <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
          <i class="uil uil-apps"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main class="l-main"></main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have a class named 'show-menu' so adding it to the element would make no effect

Comment: i recently deleted it and tried a new one and forgot to change it before uploading

Comment: so is the issue fixed?

Comment: in the following line navMenu.classList.add('show-menu') replace 'show-menu' with 'show'

Comment: in the css file i changed it back to show-menu

Comment: i would recommend you to refollow the tutorial because I have noticed you have made many minor mistakes for eg. you have <body> tag before <html> tag, you have misspelled toggle while importing navToggle and maybe many more